# Use existing javascript to trigger if else in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following script within a page on my site which adds + - buttons to a qty entry field:

```
<script language="javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {          
var $cartAdd = jQuery('#cartAdd')
  , $quantity = $cartAdd.find('input');   
$cartAdd.append('<div class="inc button">+</div><div class="dec button">-</div>');
jQuery(".back").change(function(){
     $quantity.val(1).change();
});

$cartAdd.click(function(evt) {
  var $incrementor = jQuery(evt.target)
    , quantity = parseInt($quantity.val(), 10);

  if($incrementor.hasClass('inc')) {
    quantity += 1;
  } else if($incrementor.hasClass('dec')) {
    quantity += -1;
  }

  if(quantity > 0) {
    $quantity.val(quantity);
    xhr.getPrice();
  }

 jQuery(".back").change(function(){
  xhr.getPrice();
});
});
});
</script>
```

I want to be able to hide/unhide a div when var $cartAdd goes above 1
I tried using something like

```
var $cartAdd = jQuery('#cartAdd')
  , $quantity = $cartAdd.find('input');
<?php $trigger = "<script>document.write(quantity)</script>"?>
```

followed by

```
<?php echo $trigger;?>
```

and i expected that to echo the value in the entry box but it didn't.

Is it achievable?

Answer (score 1):

You must understand that all php scripts are executed BEFORE the javascript.

What's wrong with simply grabbing the quantity and hiding if needed?

```
if( $('#cartAdd').find('input').val() > 1 ) 
{ $('#div_we_want_to_hide').hide() }
```

just put that inside a document.ready and it should work fine

Comment: >I tried this solution using a quick test div and it was always displayed. Even if i changed your solution to if( $('#cartAdd').find('input').val() = 1 ) so that it was true at page load the div was still visible whereas i would have expected it to be invisible until it changed to something other than 1

Comment: I must have a conflict somewhere as even the sample from your fiddle isn't hiding the div when it's included in the page loaded from localhost

Comment: I added var $z = jQuery.noConflict(); and the basic fiddle works now. Changed to work with my qty box and it doesn't work as i need. If i set val() > 0 it is hidden on load as default is 1. If i leave it as val() > 1 it is visible, but doesn't hide when 1 is increased to 2 using the + - buttons that are controlled by the code in the original question.
Any suggestions on how to get it to monitor for the change of value?

Comment: I'll need to see the markup, At least the basic layout. is the div you you want to hide dynamically added to the DOM? is it always there?