# Enhance existing jQuery function to hide div on increment

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an extension of a question i asked earlier. Original is here
[Use existing javascript to trigger if else in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726188/use-existing-javascript-to-trigger-if-else-in-php)

I've created a fiddle to further explain/show how the existing jQuery functions.

what i need is for the div hide to trigger when the + buttons increase the value over 1, so somehow on event.

I tried to add the

```
{ $('#foobar').hide(); }
```

in with the section where the qty is incremented, here

```
$cartAdd.click(function(evt) {
  var $incrementor = jQuery(evt.target)
    , quantity = parseInt($quantity.val(), 10);
```

but it didnt work for me.

Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/Yyb8L/1/

Comment: Hi, I guess the code to hide the div is correct, but there's an error in the code before that happens. The fiddle returns me xhr is undefined. Solve it, you'll solve the problem.

Comment: you only check the value on page load, need to check it after user interaction

Comment: @GiancarloPSK xhr is used in the function that updates the displayed price when someone presses the + - buttons. It's returning undefined as that function is not in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, on the event that your #cartAdd input is clicked, you'd like to check to see if the value of iterator has increased to greater than 1, and then hide the #foobar div.

In order to do this, you would first need to update the value each time the 'inc' and 'dec' buttons are clicked.

```
if($incrementor.hasClass('inc')) {
    quantity += 1;
    $quantity.val(quantity);  //the value of $quantity is updated
} else if($incrementor.hasClass('dec')) {
    quantity += -1;
    $quantity.val(quantity); //the value of $quantity is updated
}
```

Second, you would need to wrap your if/then block in a function, which would be called on the event the input gets clicked.

```
function checkIncrement(){    
    if( $('#cartAdd').find('input').val() > 1 ) 
    { $('#foobar').hide(); }
}
```

The function should be invoked only after the quantities have been updated, like so:

```
 $cartAdd.click(function(evt) {
  var $incrementor = jQuery(evt.target)
    , quantity = parseInt($quantity.val(), 10);

  if($incrementor.hasClass('inc')) {
    quantity += 1;
    $quantity.val(quantity); //the value of $quantity is updated
  } else if($incrementor.hasClass('dec')) {
    quantity += -1;
    $quantity.val(quantity); //the value of $quantity is updated
  }

  checkIncrement(); //checkIncrement is invoked after values are updated.

  if(quantity > 0) {
    $quantity.val(quantity);
    xhr.getPrice();
  }


    jQuery(".back").change(function(){
    xhr.getPrice();
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle of the solution http://jsfiddle.net/boomish/V7Hnw/1/

Hope this helps!

**Edit to include correct link to fiddle**

Comment: Almost there. I tried your fiddle and noticed it doesn't unhide the div if the value goes back to one.

Comment: I extended the function you gave to this function checkIncrement(){    
    if( $('#cartAdd').find('input').val() > 1 ) 
        { $('#foobar').hide(); }
     else if ( $('#cartAdd').find('input').val() <= 1 ) 
        { $('#foobar').show(); }
    console.log($('#cartAdd').find('input').val())
}   Works perfectly now. You're a star Boomish. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: One problem i have noticed is that this solution has taken away the functionality of preventing minus values from being entered in the input field. If you look at the original fiddle i posted you cannot go below 1.

Answer (score 1):

Base from what I understand on your question, you want to hide the `div` if the value of the textbox is above 1 or if the plus button was click.

I had created a simple code for you to have a basis to attain what you need.

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yyb8L/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#plus').on('click', function () {
    $('#qty').val(parseInt($('#qty').val()) + 1);
    $('#div-hide').hide();
  });

  $('#minus').on('click', function () {
    var qty = parseInt($('#qty').val()) - 1;
    $('#qty').val(qty);
    if (qty == 0) {
        $('#div-hide').show();
    }
 });
```

});

Hope that helps!

Comment: That fiddle doesn't do anything at all when incrementing the number

Comment: Sorry I seems that i did not save my edits when i copy the url.. but take a look at the fiddle now.

Comment: Almost. It needs to be visible at 1 and hide when >1

Comment: change the condition in `minus` on click event. change 0 to 1 and it will be good to go